# display array only if exists

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I made a page where users can see data entered by them in the database.
I used:

```
$select = "SELECT * FROM texts WHERE user='".$user."' ORDER BY date DESC, id DESC";
$result = mysql_query($select);
$array = array();
while($show = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
$array[] = $show;
}
echo "<strong>".$array[0]['id']."</strong><br />";
echo "<strong>".$array[1]['id']."</strong><br />";
echo "<strong>".$array[2]['id']."</strong><br />";
echo "<strong>".$array[3]['id']."</strong><br />";
echo "<strong>".$array[4]['id']."</strong><br />";
```

Code works, but sometimes I have less than 10 values to return​​, sometimes even more.
If I use  this and I have only 2 arrays to return, I get:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in ownposts.php on line 15
Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in ownposts.php on line 16
Notice: Undefined offset: 4 in ownposts.php on line 17
```

How it's possible to echo *$arrray[4]['id]* only if exist $array[4]?
I've tried with:

```
$zero = $array[0];
if(!empty($zero))
{
echo "<strong>".$zero['id']."</strong><br />";
}
$four = $array[4];
if(!empty($four))
{
echo "<strong>".$five['id']."</strong><br />";
}
```

But doesn't work as I excepted and still return *Notice: Undefined offsed: 4 in ownposts.php on line 17*.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Just move `echo` inside `while`.

Comment: Try not to use 'mysql_' functions anymore, it's deprecated and should not be used in new applications. Instead use [Mysqli](http://nl1.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://nl1.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: Still don't work if I move echo inside while.

Comment: Deprecated bla bla bla... There's absolutly no point wasting cpu time in preparing a statement that will only be ran once, and deleted on request end, as long as you properly escape input using mysql_real_escape_string.

Comment: @Virus721 and what when the code is used on a server with PHP version where the function is depreciated and not actually available? The entire script fails as you cannot select, update or insert data to the database? In which case, there's no point wasting CPU time using a function that wont work at all...

Comment: In real life companies rarely, if not never, use the latest PHP versions ;-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Undefined Index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842759/php-undefined-index)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of what you currently do, this:

```
while($show = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
$array[] = $show;
}
echo "<strong>".$array[0]['id']."</strong><br />";
echo "<strong>".$array[1]['id']."</strong><br />";
echo "<strong>".$array[2]['id']."</strong><br />";
echo "<strong>".$array[3]['id']."</strong><br />";
echo "<strong>".$array[4]['id']."</strong><br />";
```

Why not just show whatever is found by mysql as you find it:

```
while($show = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
  {
    echo "<strong>".$show['id']."</strong><br />";
  }
```

Or if you have other things to do with the array than the code you showed us, use a loop on the newly created array, ie a foreach.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
foreach($array as $data){
echo '<strong>'.$data['id'].'</strong><br />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd rewrite it as follows:

```
$i = 0;
while($show = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $array[] = $show;
    if (isset($array[$i])) {
        echo "<strong>".$array[$i]['id']."</strong><br />";
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there is function in php for that to check, array_key_exists.
You can check that at,
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php