# I am getting error "Undefined Index msg" above my form. All works Great the form too. But why am i getting the msg above the form.

Tags: php

`<?php    echo $_GET['msg'];?>`This is the line of code that i used on my contact.php.
And

```
if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers))
    header("Location:../contact.php?msg=Successful Submission! Thank You for Contacting us.");
else
    header("Location:../contact.php?msg=Error To send Email !");
```

I just see the 'msg' in this code what can be done?

Comment: See all those related questions to the right? Read any of them that have to do with an undefined index.

Comment: set your error reporting on to see what kind of error you getting .   ini_set('display', 1);
 error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: I didn't find one so i asked one.

Comment: First Google result for "php undefined index": http://stackoverflow.com/q/4842759/1359343

Answer (score 1):

Check "msg" exists first:

```
<?php if(!empty($_GET['msg']) echo $_GET['msg'];?>
```