# PHP adding information to database

Tags: php, sql

I have a slight problem here with my PHP page. I have difficulties getting the filled in data in a database.

Let me show you the code of the index;

```
<form action="aanmelden.php" method="post">
Naam: <input type="text" name="naam"><br>
Achternaam: <input type="text" name="achternaam"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
<php
$nm = $_POST['naam;];
$anm = $_POST['achternaam'];
?>
```

Now I thought I had obtained the variabled and sent to the 'aanmelden.php' file.
The contents of the aanmelden.php file are:

```
<?php
$nm = $_GET['naam'];
$anm = $_GET['achternaam'];
$connect = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'usbw'); 
mysql_select_db ('kantine'); 
$sql = "INSERT into kantine (naam, achternaam) 
VALUES ('$nm', '$anm')"; 
$res = mysql_query($sql); 
mysql_close ($connect); ?>
```

Looks all quite good to me, but when I press the submit button I get the following errors.

> **Notice**: Undefined index: naam in **I:\USBWebserver v8.6\root\aanmelden.php** on line **2**
>
> **Notice**: Undefined index: achternaam in **I:\USBWebserver
>   v8.6\root\aanmelden.php** on line **3**

Please help me out if you can.

Regards,

Demiën

Comment: Please post us the original code. Your error says that the error is with naam and archternaam, but you don't have that in your code. I am assuming you translated name and lastname for us, but this really doesn't help in debugging the specific issue.

Comment: Also check your syntax on `<php` and `$_POST['name;];` Should be `<?php` and `$_POST['name'];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your form is configured to use `method="post"`, you should be using the `$_POST` array rather than `$_GET`.

```php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$lname = $_POST['lastname'];
```

See [The Method Attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data#The_method_attribute).

Also, to avoid potential [undefined indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842759/php-undefined-index), I'd advise setting these variables with the [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary). That way, you can check for the existence of particular indexes before trying to access them.

```
$name = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : false;
$lname = isset($_POST['lastname']) ? $_POST['lastname'] : false;
```

### Edit

Other potential issues (or typos) with your code are:

```
// invalid, should be <?php
<php

// semi-colon instead of a closing quote, should be $_POST['name']
$name = $_POST['name;];
```

Answer (score 0):

Note the mismatch:

```
<form action="register.php" method="post">
                                    ^^^^

$name = $_GET['name'];
         ^^^^
```

You probably want `$_POST` instead.

And note that you are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Answer (score 0):

You are using method POST when you submit the form; however you are using the GET method to retrieve the information.

Change $_GET to $_POST on register.php and that should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want SQL Injection vulnerabilites, so I coded you a nice example of connecting to a DB and writing some values in it from POST.

```
<?php

$DB_SERVER = 'server_adress';
$DB_USER = 'mysql_server';
$DB_PASSWORD = 'myPassword';
$DB_NAME = 'myFancyDB';

try {
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $DB_SERVER . ";dbname=" . $DB_NAME, $DB_USER, $DB_PASSWORD, array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true, PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'set names utf8mb4'));
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    //Remove this Errormessage in Production as it leaks dbname + password
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

//Now the DB has been initialized.

try {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `registrierung` (Name, Lastname) VALUES (:name, :lastname);";

    $query = $db->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute(array(
        ':name' => $name,
        ':lastname' => $lastname));

    if (!$query) {
        echo 'Fail when executing query';
        exit;
    }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    //Remove this Errormessage in Production!! Leaks DB info. Replace with generic Errormessage
    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}
echo "Success!";
```

Comment: In my opinion, a specific answer to the question isn't obvious in your post. While using PDO is good advice, your answer appears to be a code rewrite without clearly addressing the OP's problem.