# Undefined index: search in C:\wamp\www\search1 (2).php on line 4

Tags: php

This is my code:

```
$button = $_GET ['submit'];
$search = $_GET ['search']; 

if(!$button)
echo "you didn't submit a keyword!";
else
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
Undefined index: search in C:\wamp\www\search1 (2).php on line 4
```

Comment: Please read the http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Use isset() before reading an array key in $_GET/$_POST/$_REQUEST.

```
$button = isset($_GET['submit']) ? $_GET['submit'] : false;
$search = isset($_GET['search']) ? $_GET['search'] : false;
if(!$button) echo "you didn't submit a keyword!";
```

[PHP Undefined Index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842759/php-undefined-index)