# Undefined index: Project_Name

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, css

I'm trying to count all my project in project table 
Project_Name is a column_name

Here is the my code I have tried:

```
<?php
   $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM project";
   $result = $connection->query($sql);  
   if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
      $row = $result->fetch_assoc();    
      $project_count = $row['Project_Name'];
   } 
   else {
      echo "0 results"; 
   } 
?>
```

Comment: the query will only return what you ask it to return

Comment: $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS Project_Name FROM project";

Comment: And what output do you get? Note that `Project_Name` is not present in your `SELECT` query so it won't be in the results either.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Undefined Index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842759/php-undefined-index)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM project";
$result = $connection->query($sql); 
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $row =$result->fetch_array();
    $project_count = $row[0];
}
```

Comment: `mysql_fetch_array` you can't mix `mysql_` functions with anything other than their own. That should read as `$result->fetch_array()` since they're using an object oriented method to connect with.

Comment: `num_rows` doesn't make sense, it will always yield a row, just get the count

Comment: thanks it works but i found way out by echo $project_count[0]; with an array but it doesnt make sense but this one should work thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The query is returning only the count. Use another query like:
`SELECT * FROM project;` for fetching the columns values in each row.
With this, you will be able to do `$row['Project_Name'];`