# Laravel 5 - Recover SESSION for PGRFileManager.php

Tags: php, laravel, ckeditor, laravel-5.1

Please, with my PGRFileManager.php (with my ckeditor),
The visitors can unfortunately access to file to this adress :
http://my-web-site.com/ckeditor/plugins/pgrfilemanager/PGRFileManager.php

To secure I want to ensure that if it is not a user of my admin, redirect (exit) the visitor ...

At Login I create a new SESSION "usercms" :

```html
<?php
public function postLogin(Request $request)
{
 $login = Auth::attempt([
       'username' => $request->input('username'),
       'password' => $request->input('password')
      ], $request->input('remember'));

 if ($login) {
  Session::put('usercms', 'EXISTE');  // CREATE SESSION
  ...
 }
}
```

OK.
_But the prolem, in my PGRFileManager.php, with this code :

```html
<?php
session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION['usercms']);
```

Wamp return this error :
"Notice: Undefined index: usercms in C:\wamp\www___Laravel\my-web-site\ckeditor\plugins\pgrfilemanager\PGRFileManager.php on line 4"

What is the solution please?
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the key 'usercms' exists in the session.

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['usercms']) && $_SESSION['usercms'] == 'EXISTE') {
  // good
} else {
  die('Unauthorized.');
}
```

See answers here:
[PHP Undefined Index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842759/php-undefined-index)

Comment: Thank, but no it does not. Although I am authenticated is the die ('Unauthorized.') Which appears